# Use SSM parameter whose name depends on a CFN parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-parameter-store

I have a CloudFormation template that looks something like the following:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  env:
    Type: String
    Default: NONE
Resources:
  GraphQLAPI:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'my-api-${env}'
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: <something>
        AwsRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
```

Suppose that I already have a SSM parameter named `/dev/cognitoUserPoolId`. When I create this template, passing env=dev, I want to use the value of that parameter as the `UserPoolId`. I want to avoid manually passing a new CFN parameter for every SSM parameter, as there may be quite a few in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use dynamic references to the SSM parameters in your template.

Something like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  env:
    Type: String
    Default: NONE
Resources:
  GraphQLAPI:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'my-api-${env}'
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${env}/cognitoUserPoolId:1}}'
        AwsRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Comment: This looks almost perfect — but the docs say that you have to hard-code a specific parameter version into the template. This would seem to make the feature useless, because if a parameter is updated for one environment, then the required version numbers wouldn't be the same as in other environments. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @ThomSmith Yes, that is true... In "cognitoUserPoolId:1", the '1' in this case is the version number of the data in the SSM Stored Parameter. This needs to be manually incremented in your template every time the data changes, because SSM Increments that when it is updated. AWS has acknowledged that, at this time, there is no way to tell a CFN template to use the LATEST version of the SSM Stored Parameter. I am hoping this is something that comes in the future.

Comment: You can add a custom CloudFormation resource for lambda that queries the parameter store api for the most recent version and returns that integer. Then, you can sub that into your string. Shouldn’t take much to throw together a python function.

Comment: I haven't written any custom resources yet, but that seems reasonable. Might be simpler just to write a resource that returns the latest value, rather than the latest version number.

Comment: (The custom resource suggestion could be a separate answer of its own.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Thom. There are merits to each approach (custom resource to return latest version number vs custom resource to return entire param value). I err on the side of making a custom resource do the least amount of work necessary as the more you make it do the more you have to consider; but I'm a keep it simple guy.